# Pythonic way to insert a DataFrame column and calculate its values from each column in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame column (from my project [here](https://github.com/nabelekt/historical_stock_growth)) that prints like this:

```
  ticker  2021-02-11 21:04  2021-01-12_close  2020-02-11_close  2016-02-11_close
0   AAPL            134.94        128.607819         79.287888         21.787796
1   MSFT            244.20        214.929993        182.506607         45.343704
```

This gives a stock ticker and its current price followed by the close price on given dates. I am looking for a pythonic way to, after each `X_close` column, insert an `X_return` column and calculate the return between the current price and the `X` price. What is a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit: When I say "calculate the return", I mean, for example, to do:

```
((134.94 - 128.607819) / 128.607819) * 100
```

So, simply using `div()` or `sub()` isn't quite satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. `df.filter` to select the `close` columns,
2. then `.sub` to subtract the selected column
3. join back
4. sort the columns with `sort_index`. You may need to play with this.

All code:

```
df.join(df.filter(like='close').sub(df['2021-02-11 21:04'], axis=0)
   .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('close','return'))
).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. Instead of subtracting, how could I do a custom operation? Using `map()` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. The idea is to simply create the new columns first and concatenate it to the dataframe.

```
df_returns = (df[cols].div(df["2021-02-11 21:04:00"], axis=0)).rename(columns = (lambda x: x.split('_')[0]+'_return'))

df_new = pd.concat([df, df_returns], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Optionally, you could resort the indices for better graphic utility:

```
df_new[df_new.columns[:-3:-1].union(df_new.columns[:-2], sort=False)]
```

For a more customized approach use pandas apply method.

```
df_returns = (df[cols].apply(foo, axis=0))
def foo(s: pd.Series):
    #Series specific changes
    ans = pd.Series()
    for i in s.shape[0]:
        ans.iloc[i] = some_func(s.iloc[i])
    #Rename series index for convenience
```

Hope this helps! You can perform any opps you like in some_func()

Comment: Thanks! This gets me close, but what I actually want to do besides straight division is `(df[cols] - df["2021-02-11 21:04:00"])/df["2021-02-11 21:04:00"]`. How can I use a custom function instead of `div`?

Comment: Hmm.. you'd need to do something like this. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Combining ideas from the answers given with my own, here is my solution:

```
def calculate_returns(df):

    print(df)
    print()

    # Get dataframe of return values
    returns_df = df.apply(calculate_return_row, axis=1)
    
    # Append returns df to close prices df
    df = pd.concat([df, returns_df], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
    
    # Rearrange columns so that close price precedes each respective return value
    return_cols = df.columns[2::2]
    close_cols  = df.columns[3::2]
    reordered_cols = list(df.columns[0:2])
    reordered_cols = reordered_cols + [col for idx, _ in enumerate(return_cols) for col in [close_cols[idx], return_cols[idx]]]
    df = df[reordered_cols]

    print(df)

    return df


def calculate_return_row(row: pd.Series):

    current_price = row[1]
    close_prices  = row[2:]
    
    returns = [calculate_return(current_price, close_price) for close_price in close_prices]
    index = [label.replace('close', 'return') for label in row.index[2:]]
    returns = pd.Series(returns, index=index)

    return returns


def calculate_return(current_val, initial_val):

    return (current_val - initial_val) / initial_val * 100
```

This avoids loops, and puts the return columns after the close columns:

```
  ticker  2021-02-12 20:37  2021-01-13_close  2020-02-12_close  2016-02-12_close
0   AAPL          134.3500        130.694702         81.170799         21.855232
1   MSFT          243.9332        216.339996        182.773773         46.082863

  ticker  2021-02-12 20:37  2021-01-13_close  2021-01-13_return  2020-02-12_close  2020-02-12_return  2016-02-12_close  2016-02-12_return
0   AAPL          134.3500        130.694702           2.796822         81.170799          65.515187         21.855232         514.726938
1   MSFT          243.9332        216.339996          12.754555        182.773773          33.461818         46.082863         429.336037
```

Thanks!